# Memcached - SERVER_ERROR out of memory storing object

Tags: memcached, out-of-memory

i'm getting the error in Memcached every now and then.

```
SERVER_ERROR out of memory storing object
```

i still have plenty of memory available on my system (5GB). My Monitoring Plugin (Nagios) tells me that i'm currently using 69% of the available memory for Memcached (`-m 1024`)

Those are the stats:

```
STAT pid 26944
STAT uptime 2127214
STAT time 1369169586
STAT version 1.4.13
STAT libevent 2.0.16-stable
STAT pointer_size 64
STAT rusage_user 59272.524301
STAT rusage_system 65565.313576
STAT curr_connections 8
STAT total_connections 51640235
STAT connection_structures 1001
STAT reserved_fds 20
STAT cmd_get 4558313652
STAT cmd_set 3486996973
STAT cmd_flush 0
STAT cmd_touch 0
STAT get_hits 3399062933
STAT get_misses 1159250719
STAT delete_misses 5140552
STAT delete_hits 1062598
STAT incr_misses 0
STAT incr_hits 0
STAT decr_misses 0
STAT decr_hits 0
STAT cas_misses 0
STAT cas_hits 0
STAT cas_badval 0
STAT touch_hits 0
STAT touch_misses 0
STAT auth_cmds 0
STAT auth_errors 0
STAT bytes_read 1221665161161
STAT bytes_written 372602026218
STAT limit_maxbytes 1073741824
STAT accepting_conns 1
STAT listen_disabled_num 418
STAT threads 4
STAT conn_yields 32569435
STAT hash_power_level 21
STAT hash_bytes 16777216
STAT hash_is_expanding 0
STAT expired_unfetched 195561
STAT evicted_unfetched 0
STAT bytes 745210506
STAT curr_items 3105071
STAT total_items 3486996973
STAT evictions 0
STAT reclaimed 263780
END
```

I'm experiencing this storing values using [spymemcached](https://code.google.com/p/spymemcached/) - but i believe it has nothing to do with it.

Furthermore, i believe that this could be fixed, if i restart the memcached server.

This is not a bug described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/memcached/QD7a-6JdqgA) which appears in versions <= 1.4.10 - I'm using 1.4.13 on Ubuntu 64bit precise.

Just found out, that i'm using the `-M` option which the manual describes as:

```
Disable automatic removal of items from the cache when out of memory. Additions will not be possible until adequate space is freed up.
```

So, i guess the memory of the memcached server is indeed full - but it doesn't use 100% of the space according to the stats - How come?

What do?

Comment: I'm facing similar issue with memcached 1.4.14, were you able to reolve your issue, did you get any solution as to why this is heppening ? Appreciate if you can help in this regard.

Comment: Me too.  My boss thinks it is because the respective slab is full, because the memcached-tool shows this by using the free_chunks_end metric, however my understanding is that slabs don't have a memory limit, only the entire process is limited by -m xxxx so how can one slab be full?